# python 2.7 how to use a time stamp that is utc on another server

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my timestamp on my utc server:

```
2016-11-21T15:35
1479742500
```

Now for debugging purposes...

I convert to a datetime object but this is what I get:

```
 datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1479742500)
 2016-11-21 23:35:00+00:00
```

How do I fix so its 2016-11-21T15:35?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the proper method, `utcfromtimestamp`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1479742500)
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 7, 35)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1479742500)
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 15, 35)
```